# Is my data safe if I run an android app (a game) on emulator inside a virtual machine

Tags: privacy, android

I want to play a very popular game made for mobile platform, but, my father doesn't allow me to touch any smartphone.
I tried bluestacks to play it on my pc. But, while installing the game, its privacy policy says that it might collect some personal data. So, I decided to use a virtual machine over which I would use an emulator to play that game.
Could that game still collect any information from the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will gather information **about** your host machine, but it will not be able to browse your host machine to gather data.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. I have installed the game and enjoying it a lot, without any fear now. I do not have the permission to upvote anything here, so just accepted your answer (without any upvote).